# I think that this variable is referencing?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple WordPress shortcode that is getting an unexpected result. This is the one that doesn't work:

```
$this_post_id = do_shortcode('[cred_post_parent get="id"]');
$testString = $this_post_id;
$parent_id = wpcf_pr_post_get_belongs($testString, 'wa-listing');
$variableType1 = gettype( $testString );
$variableType2 = gettype( $this_post_id );
$variableType3 = gettype( $parent_id );
return $variableType1.': '.$testString.' | '.$variableType2.': '.$this_post_id.' | '.$variableType3.': '.$parent_id;
```

This returns: string: 468 | string: 468 | boolean:

If I hard code in the value for $testString on the second line like so:

`$testString = '468';`

The result is: string: 468 | string: 468 | string: 56

The last variable is now returning what I need.

My suspicion is that the variable $this_post_id is referencing the object in the shortcode but I am not succeeding in trying to get around this.

Comment: Use `var_dump($variable)` or `debug_zval_dump($variable)` to see the content, the type and (using the latter) the refcount of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a good idea to read more about do_shortcode function functionality from official documentation - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/ and understand what it returns and hot to use it in your situation?

In your case do_shortcode doesn't work properly - returnd full string that you passed to it as param '[cred_post_parent get="id"]', so

```
$parent_id = wpcf_pr_post_get_belongs($testString, 'wa-listing');
```

returns false and

```
$variableType3 = gettype( $parent_id );
```

returns boolean
so code works perfectly, the problem in logic. The problem in how you call

```
$this_post_id = do_shortcode('[cred_post_parent get="id"]');
```

Try to read more about this function and what params they need get get her job done.

Does it help?